# How can I add all of the numbers in a stack together and then print the total?

Tags: java, stack, processing

I don't know how to add all of the things in a stack together.

I already have:

```
  Stack <Integer> stack = new Stack <Integer>();
  stack.push(15);
  stack.push(30);
  int total = 0;
  while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
     print(total);
  }
```

This repeatedly printed 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Stacks have both a `push` and a `pop` method. The `push` method pushes an object down onto the stack and the `pop` method pops the top object off the stack. Each call to push will increase the stack size by 1 and each pop will decrease the stack size by 1.

With a small modification to your code we can total up all the numbers that have been added to your stack.

```
 import java.util.Stack;

 Stack <Integer> stack = new Stack <Integer>();
  stack.push(15);
  stack.push(30);
  int total = 0;
  while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    total += stack.pop();
  }
  print(total);
```